# compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle. Error while generating SSH key

Tags: firebase, react-native, build.gradle, gradlew

I'm trying to generate SSH key using ./gradlew signingReport for react native app, but it keeps on giving two error. "compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradl" and "Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0."

```
Below is the versions i'm using.
Gradle:       7.3.3
Kotlin:       1.5.31
Groovy:       3.0.9
JVM:          17.0.5 (Oracle Corporation 17.0.5+9-LTS-191)
OS:           Mac OS X 12.4 aarch64
```

app/build.gradle

```
android {
ndkVersion rootProject.ext.ndkVersion

compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'com.pushapp.leel'
    minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
    targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0.0"
    buildConfigField "boolean", "IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED", isNewArchitectureEnabled().toString()
```

I've tried most solutions provided here and other places but didn't work. I need help fixing this issue or some references to similar issues.